# getting my user id to pass it to my employee

Tags: php, sql

```
    <?php
                if(isset($_SESSION['id']) ) {
                    if ($_SESSION['id']) {
                        //echo "you're login";
                        }
                echo "<form action='upload.php' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post'>
                        <br>Qr Code:
                        <p><input type='file' name='file' >
                        <p><input type='submit' value='Upload' name='submit'>
                      </form>";
                }
    ?>

<?php
```

$statusMsg = '';

```
// File upload path
$targetDir = "qr_code/";
$fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
$fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
    // Allow certain file formats
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif','JPG','PNG','GIF','JPEG');
    if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
        // Upload file to server
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
            // Insert image file name into database
            $insert = $db->query("INSERT into qr (file_name, uploaded_on) 
                                    VALUES ('".$fileName."', NOW())");
            if($insert){
                $statusMsg = "The file ".$fileName. " has been uploaded successfully.";
                    header ("Location:employee.php?uploadsuccess");
            }else{
                $statusMsg = "File upload failed, please try again.";

            }
        }else{
            $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }else{
        $statusMsg = 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF files are allowed to upload.';
    }
}else{
    $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.';
}

// Display status message
echo $statusMsg;
?>

<?php
      
    
    
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM qr  ORDER BY uploaded_on DESC limit 1 ");

if($query->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        $imageURL = 'qr_code/'.$row["file_name"];
?>
    <img src="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" alt="" />
<?php }
}else{ ?>
      <img src="images/qr.png" alt="" />
<?php } ?>
```

> I'm having a problem where they have two different primary keys and I want my employee to get the user's id so that I can upload a photo specifically for him/her.
> I want my employee to upload an image just for my specific user in my database
> let's say my employee's primary id is 12 while my user's primary key is 2.

Comment: do you not have an endpoint that has the employee id, i.e  `/admin/employee/2`? if so then use the id from that, if not then what defines the admin is at employee 2?

Comment: can i just use get['id];?

Comment: yeah table for uploaded images and table for my users,employee

Comment: sorry, I thought you were having issue getting/knowing the id if logged in as admin.. if its just about linking user row to employee row, then use a `users_id` column in `employee`, a one to one relationship

Comment: tip, don't pluralise your table names

Comment: i tried using the users_id but it's just not showing up my uploaded images for my user

Comment: would help to see your code

Comment: code for my upload images? or all of it?

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion, you should make a foreign key in employee table to join with your table like this.

| Employee_id | employee_idf |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 1 |
| 12 | 2 |
| 13 | 3 |

while your structure no need change